# Get attached files with InboxSDK and send them via Gmail API

Tags: gmail-api, inboxsdk

I am using [InboxSDK](https://www.inboxsdk.com/) and [gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send) on PHP to build a chrome extension.

Everything is flowing quite okay so far, but I am facing a big obstacle.

**What is my purpose?**:

Via InboxSDK, I want to handle when a user attaches files.

Send all the information to my server.

Attach the files and send the mail via Gmail API from the server.

**Where am I?**:

I already authorize the user with OAuth2.0 and keep the tokens and also I am already able to send the e-mails written in Gmail Web via server Gmail API.

I do not know how to move on with handling the files.

How may I proceed?

Also, if there is any alternative way to achieve this without InboxSDK I am happy to hear.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible as mentioned.

But there is a workaround.

- Create a draft via InboxSDK.
- Fetch the draft via gmail API.
- Send the created draft, which already contains the attached files.